# sha1sum コマンドでチェックサム取得時に絶対パスではなくファイル名のみで出力する方法を教えてください

Tags: linux

### 前提

指定のフォルダ配下のファイルのチェックサムを取得したく、コマンドを以下のように書きました。
⚫︎コマンド

```
find /var/log -type f | xargs sha1sum
```

⚫︎実行結果

```
チェックサム  /var/log/wtmp
チェックサム  /var/log/mailog
```

### 質問

上記出力を

```
チェックサム　　wtmp
チェックサム　　maillog
```

としたいです。

```
echo /var/log | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```

でファイル名のみ出力することはできましたが、それをどのようにチェックサム取得コマンドに組み合わせたら良いでしょうか？
また、他に良い方法がありましたらご教示願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
find /var/log -type f | xargs sha1sum | awk -F/ '{print $1, $NF}'
```

Comment: 想定していた結果が出力されました！ありがとうございます。
もう1点お聞きしたいのですが、出力した「チェックサム　　wtmp」の間をスペース1つのみにしたい場合、どのようなオプションがベストかご教示いただけないでしょうか？
awk -F/ '{print $1" "$NF}'では特に変化がありませんでした。。。

Comment: `awk -F'[/ ]' '{print $1, $NF}'` としてみてください。(区切り文字をスラッシュかスペースにします)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！意図した内容で出力できました！！

Answer (score 0):

ファイル名だけの場合、サブディレクトリにファイルがあると困る気がしました。サブディレクトリに存在しない（もしくはサブディレクトリのファイルは無視する）場合はもっと簡単に

```
(cd /var/log; sha1sum *)
```

でいいかと。`()`で括ったのは完了後にカレントディレクトリを戻すためで、戻さなくてもよいなら括る必要はありません。